# Python - Replace date column with progressive number

Tags: python

I've this DataFrame, called X

```
            Open    High     Low   Close  Volume Currency
Date                                                      
2019-05-10  250.4  254.40  250.40  252.00  993567      EUR
2019-05-13  252.0  253.30  245.65  245.80  857825      EUR
```

I need to replace the Date value with 1,2,3,4 etc..
I've tried with:

```
test = X.pop('Date')
```

but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` in an index in your dataframe, so can use `reset_index` to remove it.

```
# creating a df similar to yours
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Date": "2019-05-10", "Open": 250.4}, 
    {"Date": "2019-05-10", "Open": 252.0}
]).set_index("Date")
out: 
             Open
Date             
2019-05-10  250.4
2019-05-10  252.0

# remove the index
df = df.reset_index(level="Date", drop=True)
out:
    Open
0  250.4
1  252.0
```